# Javascript Shift table position up if the table is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```html
<html>
<head>


<script language="JavaScript">

    function showMe(cls) {
        var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
        var vis =0;
        for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
            if (chboxs[i].checked) {
                vis =1;
                break;
            }
        }
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
        for (let e of elements) {
            e.style.opacity = vis;
        }
    }
</script>

</head>


                <br>
                <table class="header" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                <td align="left">
                <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('box')">Show Result
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                
                <table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                <td class="uniqueborder" width="90%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Event</b></td>
                <td class="uniqueborder" width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Status</b></td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                <table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-right:1px solid #CBCBCB; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px"align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody></table>
                <table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                <table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                <table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    
                </tbody></table></table>

</html>
```

This piece of code able show the hidden table using checkbox. The problem is that if the checkbox is not checked, there is a spot between two tables. How can I delete or move the table up? Or the script automatically merge it? When you click the checkbox a few times, you can see the spot between tables. Also, you can think that many tables have spot each other. I just share a piece of code with you.

```
<html>
<head>


<script language="JavaScript">

    function showMe(cls) {
        var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
        var vis =0;
        for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
            if (chboxs[i].checked) {
                vis =1;
                break;
            }
        }
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
        for (let e of elements) {
            e.style.opacity = vis;
        }
    }
</script>

</head>


                <br>
                <table class="header" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                <td align="left">
                <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('box')">Show Result
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                
                <table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                <td class="uniqueborder" width="90%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Event</b></td>
                <td class="uniqueborder" width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Status</b></td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                <table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-right:1px solid #CBCBCB; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px"align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody></table>
                <table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                <table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                <table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left"><p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p></td>
                          <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%"><font color="gray">N/A</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    
                </tbody></table></table>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you making it transparent? Why are you not actually hiding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move from setting the `opacity` "0/1" to set the `display` "none/table".
The `opacity` property does not affect dimensions like `height`.

Your HTML code is still the same.

Here's a working live [Codepen](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/zYrEJWZ).

```html
 <table class="header" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <input type="checkbox" name="c1" onclick="showMe('box')">Show Result
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="uniqueborder" width="90%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Event</b></td>
        <td class="uniqueborder" width="10%" align="center" bgcolor="#F3F3F3"><b>Status</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
            <p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p>
        </td>
        <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
            <font color="gray">N/A</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
            <p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p>
        </td>
        <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
            <font color="gray">N/A</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-right:1px solid #CBCBCB; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px" align="left">
                <p style="margin: 0pt; ">Test </p>
            </td>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
                <font color="gray">N/A</font>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
                <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p>
            </td>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
                <font color="gray">N/A</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
                <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p>
            </td>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
                <font color="gray">N/A</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="uniqueborder" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
                <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p>
            </td>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
                <font color="gray">N/A</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
                <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p>
            </td>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
                <font color="gray">N/A</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="box" width="100%" bordercolor="#CBCBCB" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
                <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Test input:</span></p>
            </td>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
                <font color="gray">N/A</font>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="left">
                <p style="margin: 0pt; "><span class="bluebold">1. Expected</span></p>
            </td>
            <td class="uniqueborder" align="center" width="10%">
                <font color="gray">N/A</font>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
</table>
```

```js
function showMe(cls) {
    var chboxs = document.getElementsByName("c1");
    var vis = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < chboxs.length; i++) {
        if (chboxs[i].checked) {
            vis = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);
    for (let e of elements) {
        if (vis === 1) {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            e.style.display = 'table';
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :)